# Как изменить размеры bounding box в irrlicht 3D?

Tags: c++, 3d, irrlicht

Как изменить размеры бокса ноды в ирлихте? По умолчаию бокс объемом с модель, но модели разные бывают. В моем случае маленькие ноги и оооочень большая голова, итог, бокс в разы больше (в плоскости ХZ) чем ноги, и герой скачет по платформам, цепляясь воздухом. Решение вижу одно - отдельный бокс, который перемещать вместе с героем. Может есть способ лучше?